# Creating an eCryptfs Filesystem

Tags: ecryptfs

I have a number of user directories that I'd like to have encrypted and authenticated via eCryptfs.

I am attempting to create a new filesystem like so:

```
gpg2 --decrypt key.gpg | \
  sudo mount -t ecryptfs -o key=passphrase:passphrase_passwd_fd=0 \
    /home/naftuli/.private/Documents/Secure \
    /home/naftuli/Documents/Secure
```

The goal is that I can have multiple encrypted filesystems, opening only the ones that I actually *need* and closing them when done, being able to make backups of `$HOME/.private` which will be the encrypted and authenticated filesystem entries for the given filesystems, and being able to sync these filesystems using something like Syncthing without ever knowing what's actually inside.

What is the process for creating an eCryptfs mount point? I have not been successful so far, receiving kernel errors:

```
Error attempting to evaluate mount options: [-22] Invalid argument
Check your system logs for details on why this happened.
Try updating your ecryptfs-utils package, and/or
submit a bug report on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ecryptfs
```

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04, kernel 4.4.0.

[The tutorials I have found](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-encrypt-directories-and-partitions-with-ecryptfs-on-debian/) seem to suggest that what I'm trying above should work, but it obviously does not.

Answer (score 1):

- Option 1: use named pipes and `passphrase_passwd_file` instead of fd. Managing stdin/out and reading/writing from pipes at the same time could be some challenge (cf. https://gist.github.com/korc/15886e50999af9701bad967534e84770).
- Option 2: do a bit preparation and use `/sbin/mount.ecryptfs_private` with *alias* argument (here: `xxx`). Adding keys and mounting is actually 2 separate procedures, linked through keys in kernel keyring (cf. `keyctl` command)

  1. add encryption keys to kernel keyring with `ecryptfs-add-passphrase`. `keyctl show` is also quite useful. If you use pam_ecryptfs, some
     keys might already be there (if you have done `ecryptfs-setup-private`). Looking inside
     `/usr/bin/ecryptfs-mount-private` could give some hints, too.
  2. create `$HOME/.ecryptfs/xxx.conf` and `xxx.sig`, cf. `man mount.ecryptfs_private` for reference. In short, `.conf` file is fstab-like description of mountpoints and `.sig` contains key signatures (should match `keyctl` output).
  3. Use `/sbin/mount.ecryptfs_private xxx` to mount, `/sbin/umount.ecryptfs_private xxx` to unmount.